# How to cancel SubscriptionSchedule in stripe api using php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to cancel any Subscription that I created in StripeAPI.
I have schedule id from created schedule subscription.
How to cancel schedule subscription in php?
I tried to call cancel function.

```
\Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::cancel
```

But I face below error:

> Deprecated: Non-static method Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::cancel()
> should not be called statically

Could you tell me what function should be called and what params I should use?

Comment: The deprecation warning is telling you that instead of `::cancel` you should use `->cancel`. That's about it.

Comment: now my code is \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::cancel
I can't use \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule->cancel
To use this, I need to create SubscriptionSchedule instance.
How to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stripe-php library added support for client and services in 7.33.0. This is documented in details [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0). If you're on a version after that one, you can call the `cancel()` method on the service directly which is what the API Reference shows [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/cancel?lang=php):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_123');

$stripe->subscriptionSchedules->cancel('sub_sched_ABC');
```

On the other hand, if you have an older version of the library, you need to use the old methods via the resource. In that case, there wasn't a static `cancel()` method (one of the upsides of the services infrastructure). Because of this, you had to retrieve the schedule first and then cancel it:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_123');

$schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::retrieve('sub_sched_ABC');
$schedule->cancel();
```